# How to capture screenshot on KaiOS device (Nokia 8110 4G)

Tags: mobile, screenshot, kaios

Does anyone know how to capture screenshot on Nokia 8110 4G (KaiOS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Yes it is - Joelbert W's answer worked and makes the other responses a bit silly by comparison, just `*` and `#` together :-)

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible :-(

https://twitter.com/KaiHelps/status/1072446931421593603
https://twitter.com/KaiHelps/with_replies

Answer (score 4):

You may follow these steps to get screenshot via Firefox WebIDE.

1. On the device - dial `*#*#33284#*#*` to enable developer mode. There will be a bug icon on the status bar.
2. Download Firefox 58.
3. [**Important**] Disable your internet access, this is to prevent Firefox got updated to a newer version which might break the WebIDE functionality.
4. Launch Firefox 58 and disable auto update.
5. Resume your internet access.
6. Launch WebIDE in Tools > Web Developer > WebIDE.
7. Restart the WebIDE (because the ADB helper would be downloaded automatically, and need to restart it to take effect.)
8. Now you should be able to see Nokia 8110 detected under "USB devices" at the right panel. (if not, see below)
9. Click the device, "Nokia 8110", and then click Screenshot.

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsd4H.jpg) for a sample screenshot.

---

Troubleshooting if you failed to see Nokia 8110 detected:

1. I found it might fail if your Firefox got updated to a newer version automatically, in this case you might need to leverage creating new profile to start over again, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiple_profiles) for details.
2. If the Firefox version stays correctly at 58 but after you click the device, it shows an error saying "Failed to connect", try to reboot the phone and also restart the WebIDE as this [post](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/7455/how-to-connect-from-web-ide) suggested.

Comment: Interesting. Will give it a try and will let you know. Thanks for the suggestions. Though the original question was about the device itself without any connection of FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible either with WebIDE connection or with a custom ROM such as [GerdaOS](https://gerda.tech) where you can make screenshots by pressing Power with half-open slide lid.

However, I'd only recommend installing custom ROMs for experienced users only since you can't use any official updates after installing them.

Comment: nice; did not know there is a custom ROM build for that. though I do not think I am in the position of installing it in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

So I have a go flip 3, and i stumbled on if u press * and # almost simultaneously, it takes a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible on certain devices and OS versions using the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) as well.

Answer (score -1):

On 8110, screenshots are not possible using the device itself. Newer devices support `*` + `#` to take a screenshot and save it in Gallery. However, you can take screenshots using another device, usually a PC or Android tablet.

To reach this goal, you first have to enable debugging on your phone. [Here's a guide on BananaHackers wiki](https://wiki.bananahackers.net/devices/nokia-8110-4g) about 8110.

Briefly, you first dial `*#*#33284#*#*` to enable the debug mode. Then connect your phone with a USB cable to a PC, launch WebIDE, connect to the phone and finally take a screenshot using the Screenshot button. And all these must be done after environment setup as documented in [the KaiOS developer portal](https://developer.kaiostech.com/docs/getting-started/env-setup/os-env-setup).

Regarding WebIDE, you've got many choices. One of them being a Firefox version older than 59, Waterfox Classic 2022.11, older versions of Palemoon and perhaps many other Firefox forks.

If you don't like an entire big software like WebIDE just for screenshots, alternatively you can use [KaiScr](https://notabug.org/farooqkz/Kaiscr).

Last but not the least, it is also possible to take screenshots using the device if you are willing to root and mod your device and your don't care about warranty and risks: https://wiki.bananahackers.net/en/Customizations/screenshots-on-8110